# Replacing registry default value from command line

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-registry

I'm modifying an entry in the Windows registry. In the key there is a single value called `(Default)` of type `REG_SZ`. This value is not set.

I've tried using `REG Add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\.jpg" /f /v "(Default)" /t REG_SZ /d "PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Tiff"` to change the data associated with `(Default)`, but instead it creates a second `(Default)` value underneath the original, like so:

[image]

How can I correctly replace this information without using a `reg` file? I want to stick to the command line for the purposes of this project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### How can I correctly replace this information

```
REG Add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\.jpg" /f /v "(Default)" /t REG_SZ /d "PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Tiff"
```

Use the `/ve` option (Set the (default) value) instead of `/v`:

```
REG Add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\.jpg" /ve /d "PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Tiff" /f
```

---

#### Syntax

> `REG ADD [ROOT\]RegKey /ve [/d Data] [/f]`  -- Set the (default) value

Source [reg](http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [reg](http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html) - Read, Set or Delete registry keys and values, save and restore from a .REG file.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `/ve` instead of `/v` like this:
`REG Add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\.jpg" /f /ve /d "PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Tiff"`

Comment: You don't need `/t REG_SZ` as the default value is already a string.

Comment: You're right. Edited this.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: `/ve`      adds an empty value name (Default) for the key.

So the correct Command-line would be:

```
REG Add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\.jpg" /f /ve /t REG_SZ /d "PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Tiff"
```

Or the shorter form.

```
REG Add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\.jpg" /f /ve /t REG_SZ /d "PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Tiff"
```

Comment: You don't need `/t REG_SZ` as the default value is already a string.

Comment: Correct. But the force of habit. And I prefer to include it for the sake of uniformity.